# catch sys.exit with py.test

Tags: python, generator, pytest

How do I catch `sys.exit()` with pytest in a function that returns a generator? In the following code, `f()` only returns *hello world* if `x = True`. But using `x = False`, I expect the code to launch `SystemExit`.

```
def test_generator():
    with pytest.raises (SystemExit) as excinfo:
        def f(x = True):
            if x:
                yield 'hello world'
            sys.exit('Test')
        f (x = False)
    assert 'Test' == excinfo.value
```

py.test complains that the exception was not raised. If I change `yield` by `return`, the code works without any problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to patch `sys` with `mock.patch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely calling a generator function does not execute ANY of the code inside it - that only happens when you iterate over the returned generator.  Try `list(f(x=False))`, or perhaps `f(x=False).next()`.